# DocuSign API Webhook for add/remove signers?

Tags: docusignapi

I've already been successfully using the envelope eventNotification webhooks to receive status updates for various envelope and signer events (Sent, Delivered, Completed, etc.), but I'm trying to solve one last event case: adding and removing signers from the envelope.

Suppose in a situation where envelopes are shared among multiple people in a company:
 1. Someone creates an envelope through the API, and adds 3 signers.
 2. Someone else makes corrections to the envelope using DocuSign's web site, and removes a signer...

Is there any way for my app to know that action #2 took place?  Or do I have to wait for one of the regular signer events to take place before I will know that the signers on the envelope have changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect event triggers for the start and finish of Envelope Correct are a good idea. You'd use the finish trigger to figure out what has happened.

This enhancement request is internally logged at DocuSign as CONNECT-510.
Ask your DocuSign Account Executive or Account Manager to add your organization's interest in the enhancement. It is not yet scheduled to be released, other Connect architectural work is needed first.

The history of the envelope, including correct operations is available from [Envelopes: listAuditEvents](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listAuditEvents/). You could use that today to see if someone is correcting the envelopes you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I figured that was going to be the state of things.  I'll be watching future release notes.